# How to show Time interval in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have two variable where time range is stored. 
and i have to display time interval in this format

```
09:00:00  -- 09:30:00
09:30:00  -- 10:00:00
10:00:00  -- 10:30:00
10:30:00  -- 11:00:00

UpTO

05:00:00 -- 05:30:00
```

### here is my code

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @InvTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME

SET @StartTime='09:00:00'
SET @EndTime='17:30:00'

WHILE @StartTime < @EndTime
BEGIN

    SET @InvTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @StartTime)

    PRINT CONVERT(char(8), @StartTime, 108)+ '  ' + CONVERT(char(8), @InvTime, 108) 
    SET @StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @StartTime)
END
```

anyway my code is working but looking for suggestion to achieve it by any other best way.

### My Job done. Full sql as follows

```
DECLARE     @StartTime datetime = '2015-06-09 09:00:00',
            @EndTime datetime = '2015-06-09 18:00:00',
            @Interval int = 30 -- this can be changed.

DECLARE     @PartyIntervals TABLE (
            Party1Name      VARCHAR(500),
            StartRange      DATETIME,
            EndRange        DATETIME) 

DECLARE     @CSVIntervals   TABLE (
            Party1Name      VARCHAR(500),
            Incoming        INT,
            StartRange      DATETIME) 

;WITH cSequence AS
(
    SELECT
       @StartTime AS StartRange, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, @StartTime) AS EndRange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      EndRange, 
      DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange)
    FROM cSequence 
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange) < @EndTime
)


INSERT INTO @PartyIntervals
SELECT      Party1Name, 
            StartRange,
            EndRange 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Party1Name FROM tridip_Interval) A, cSequence ORDER BY Party1Name;
--SELECT * FROM @PartyIntervals ORDER BY Party1Name

INSERT INTO @CSVIntervals
SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as incoming,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='I'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name

SELECT  P.Party1Name,
        P.StartRange,
        P.EndRange,
        IsNull(Incoming , 0) AS Incoming
FROM    @PartyIntervals P LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        @CSVIntervals A ON  A.Party1Name = P.Party1Name AND P.StartRange = A.StartRange
ORDER BY  P.Party1Name,P.StartRange
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is working here is one more alternative to create a `cte` like this:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME

SELECT @StartTime = '09:00:00'
SELECT @EndTime = '17:30:00'


;WITH interval_cte(StartTime, EndTime) AS
(
   SELECT @StartTime StartTime, DATEADD(mi, 30, @StartTime) EndTime

   UNION ALL

   SELECT EndTime, DATEADD(mi, 30, EndTime)  FROM interval_cte
   WHERE EndTime < @EndTime

)  
SELECT * FROM interval_cte
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/682)**

To get only the time interval ie, without date part try like this:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME

SELECT @StartTime = '09:00:00'
SELECT @EndTime = '17:30:00'


;WITH time_cte(StartTime, EndTime) AS
(
   SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@StartTime,108) StartTime, CONVERT(varchar,(DATEADD(mi, 30, @StartTime)),108) EndTime

   UNION ALL

   SELECT CONVERT(varchar,EndTime,108), CONVERT(varchar,(DATEADD(mi, 30, EndTime)),108)  FROM time_cte
   WHERE EndTime < @EndTime

)  
SELECT * FROM time_cte
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/686)**

Comment: all good but your code date is also showing. i need to print only hh;mm:ss.

Comment: you need to use this `CONVERT(varchar,@StartTime,108)` in your code to return only hh:mm:ss.

Comment: @Thomas:- Indeed, and that will give you what you want! :)

Comment: This is a nice example of a CTE to generate a sequence. Just to add my $0.02; it is a little neater to do the `CONVERT` in the final `SELECT *`, and more efficient in terms of CPU, so that the recursive CTE is working purely with datetimes rather than the string representations.

Comment: @RahulTripathi just one request. i am not familiar with CTE. so would u plzz explain how your CTE works? which line execute first line before union or after. specially this line not clear `SELECT EndTime, DATEADD(mi, 30, EndTime)  FROM interval_cte`

Comment: why cte has param like `time_cte(StartTime, EndTime)` ? if omit then what will happen ?

Comment: @Thomas:- Nothing will happen if you omit that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/690 I just named it for the sake of column names

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking about the formatting to convert 9:30AM 10:00AM to 09:00:00 -- 10:00:00, then you just need to change your PRINT line to the following:

```
PRINT CONVERT(varchar,@StartTime,108)+ ' -- '+CONVERT(varchar,@InvTime,108)
```